# PHP convert uploaded image

Tags: php, mysql, image

In my application there is data which is manually inserted into database and data inserted using php. In this there is a image field. The manually inserted image is of the form

```
 ÿØÿàJFIFÿÛC%...........
```

But when I upload image from form I am getting in the format

```
 ‰PNG  IHDR^¢”j× IDATxœd½Y“$Ir&¦ªv..............
```

Code:

```
 $img = imagecreatefromstring($image);
        imagepng($img, 'image.png');
        imagedestroy($img);
        $image = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents('image.png'));
```

Here `$image` is image fetched from database. The code works fine for images manually uploaded into database. For images uploaded via form it gives the error

```
Message: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error: truncated data
```

What should I do so that the uploaded image via form will work with the above code.

EDIT (upload):

```
 $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

HTML:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
        <label class="label-req" for="serial">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
 </form>
```

Comment: First of all, why are you attempting to load images into a database?  In most cases, this is a bad design approach.

Comment: How exactly are images "manually" inserted? With what? Are they base64_encoded first?

Comment: Does your form contain `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: There's also a race condition on the `image.png` file

Comment: @cen: The images are inserted using phpmyadmin

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes my form contains `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Please show us the upload form code.

Comment: How are you getting/inserting the images in the database?  What is the type of the field they are stored in?  P.S. I suggest storing the images outside of the database (in the filesystem), and storing their paths in the database.